# My website login page is not centered using current CSS

Tags: html, web

I'm not sure why the login area is not centered and why the pictures do not load in the back either

I  have tried to center them but I don't think I am doing it correctly. it just sticks up into the top left every time.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('imgbg1.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.login-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 80px 40px 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.form::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  transform: skewX(-26deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.form h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #ff652f;
}

.form .input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form .input-group input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}

.form .input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.form .input-group input:focus+label,
.form .input-group input:valid+label {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  color: #ff652f;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.submit-btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #ff652f;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-pw {
  color: inherit;
}

#forgot-pw {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#forgot-pw:target {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-wrap">
    <form action="" class="form">
      <img src="avatar.png" alt="">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="loginforUser" id="loginforUser" required>
        <label for="loginforuser">User Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" name="loginforPassword" id="loginforPassword" required>
        <label for="loginforPassword">Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-">
      <a href="#forgotpassword" class="forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i am trying to centre both ways actually, how would i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a div tag and you misspelled your class name

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('imgbg1.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.login-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 80px 40px 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.form::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  transform: skewX(-26deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.form h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #ff652f;
}

.form .input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form .input-group input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}

.form .input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.form .input-group input:focus+label,
.form .input-group input:valid+label {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  color: #ff652f;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.submit-btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #ff652f;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-pw {
  color: inherit;
}

#forgot-pw {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#forgot-pw:target {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-wrap">
    <form action="" class="form">
      <img src="avatar.png" alt="">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="loginforUser" id="loginforUser" required>
        <label for="loginforuser">User Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" name="loginforPassword" id="loginforPassword" required>
        <label for="loginforPassword">Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-">
      <a href="#forgotpassword" class="forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your class name is `login-wrap` but you misspelled as `login-wrapper`. I think the issue is with the image name or url. you have to mention the correct image path.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1103970/pexels-photo-1103970.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.login-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 380px;
  padding: 80px 40px 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.form::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  transform: skewX(-26deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.form h2 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #ff652f;
}

.form .input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form .input-group input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}

.form .input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.form .input-group input:focus+label,
.form .input-group input:valid+label {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  color: #ff652f;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.submit-btn {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #ff652f;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-pw {
  color: inherit;
}

#forgot-pw {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#forgot-pw:target {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-wrap">
    <form action="" class="form">
      <img src="avatar.png" alt="">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="loginforUser" id="loginforUser" required>
        <label for="loginforuser">User Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" name="loginforPassword" id="loginforPassword" required>
        <label for="loginforPassword">Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit-">
      <a href="#forgotpassword" class="forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```